# How to count number of working days excluding holiday in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

I am able to find difference between two dates in MySQL however same query is not working in hive.

I have a table in which we have a list of dates of holidays.

```
SELECT bd.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holiday WHERE h_date BETWEEN bd.t_date AND bd.start_date) as holiday_count
FROM   biz_date as bd
```

Error in hive:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:1 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'COUNT' '(' in expression specification (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Comment: Hi, I think that you need to rewrite your query using cross join.

Comment: can you share some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
SELECT t_date,start_date, holiday_count from biz_date as bd
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as holiday_count FROM holiday,biz_date as bd WHERE h_date BETWEEN bd.t_date AND bd.start_date) as holiday_count
ON 1=1
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--+
|   t_date    | start_date  | holiday_count  |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--+
| 2018-12-31  | 2019-02-01  | 2              |
+-------------+-------------+----------------+--+
```

Full Test Code:

```
create table temp.biz_date (                                                                                                                                                                                     
t_date                  string
,start_date)
stored as parquet location '/temp.db/biz_date' tblproperties("parquet.compression=SNAPPY";

create table temp.biz_date(
t_date                   CHAR(10) 
, start_date             CHAR(10) )
stored as parquet location '/temp.db/biz_date' tblproperties("parquet.compression=SNAPPY") ;

INSERT INTO TABLE temp.holiday VALUES ('2019-01-01'),('2019-01-05');
INSERT INTO TABLE temp.biz_date  VALUES ('2018-12-31','2019-02-01');
```